# Meteor - loop through Collection to delete the first x-many items

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have an FS Collection in Meteor called "MyUploads". I will be performing some functionality on the files uploaded into the Collection, and then additional files will be created and subsequently added within MyUploads. I have created an event, in which this will take place, called #parseUploads. Within the event, and prior to the addition of the subsequent files added to MyUploads, I have created a variable:

```
var previousCount = fileCount;
```

which is responsible for storing the original count of documents that the user had added to the Collection. Then, the parsing function will perform on each of these documents, and add the newly parsed documents to the collection.

My question is: How do I loop through the Collection from the first document up through the previousCount's value document?
In other words, if the previousCount has a value of 3 (meaning, that the user had uploaded 3 documents), then after the parsing functionality has been performed, there will be 3 subsequent documents added to the collection. I then would like to know how I can loop through the Collection and delete only the first 3 documents, while leaving the 3 subsequent documents remaining in the Collection.

Comment: What if you add a timestamp to each item, and when you make the query, keep a tmp variable of the current timestamp. Once the query is complete, run a delete operation for all those with timestamp < tmpTimestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a boolean field to the collection to act as a flag to denote parsed items.  Once an item is parsed, you can update it.

Then you can remove items from the collection based on the presence of that flag.

```
MyCollection.remove({stale: true});
```

Hope that helps,

Elliott